# Is there a way to automatically unload data in Snowflake to local machine using tasks or stored procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to automatically unload my data using Task or Stored Procedure but they didn't work out, seems like the get command wasn't run, is there a way to fix it? Thank you,

CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM unload_dimads_stream

ON TABLE "FA_PROJECT01_DB"."ADSBI"."DIM_ADS";

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK unload_dimads_task1

WAREHOUSE = FA_PROJECT01_CLOUDDW

SCHEDULE = '1 minute'

WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('unload_dimads_stream')

AS

COPY INTO @adsbi.%dim_ads from AdsBI.Dim_Ads file_format = (TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER = '|' BINARY_FORMAT = 'UTF-8' compression=none) header= true overwrite=true;

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK unload_dimads_task2

WAREHOUSE = FA_PROJECT01_CLOUDDW

AFTER unload_dimads_task1

WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('unload_dimads_stream')

AS

GET @adsbi.%dim_ads file://D:\unload\table1;

ALTER TASK unload_dimads_task2 resume;

ALTER TASK unload_dimads_task1 resume;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GET @adsbi.%dim_ads file://D:\unload\table1;
```

You cannot run this step on a stored procedure or task. Stored procedures and tasks are running on Snowflake servers. You can script GET operations outside of Snowflake using the SnowSQL client, but something else will need to call it to run.